# regex finding css block

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I have this CSS block:

```
@component HelloWorld {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 1rem;

  @modifier red {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

and I want to find all the contents in this block until the blocks end (with })

I wrote the following regex and I don't know how to ignore all of the brackets inside the block and find only the closing one.

```
[\s]{0,}@([\w]+)[ ]{1,}([\w\d]+)[ ]{0,}{.+?(?=})
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/WrGWZo/1)

and also I want to match all of the blocks if I have the following CSS:

```
@modifier red {
  color: green;
}

@modifier red {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: `.+}` will match everything before `}`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal, please look at this example: https://regex101.com/r/WrGWZo/2, i want to match two of the blocks

Comment: try this `.+?}`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal, and now I have a problem with the first example, I edited the question with more information. I hope my question is understandable

Comment: You need `[^}]*`, `\s*@(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*{[^}]+}`, see https://regex101.com/r/WrGWZo/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, try this on the first example: https://regex101.com/r/WrGWZo/5

Comment: Ok, so you need a CSS parser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this is no possible by one regex query?

Comment: No...............

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/WrGWZo/8 this is the best I can think of right now, nested blocks will create problems

Comment: thank you @VaibhavVishal, I will use CSS parser as Wiktor said.